# Going from Date() to DateTime

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am writing information to a CSV by getting data from a database like so:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    invOnboardDate = $row["invOnboardDate"];
}
```

A very basic concept here, get the row value and assign that value to a variable.

Now this is fine for most things but then I came across an interesting conundrum, one field is of type `Date` and another is of type `DateTime`.

For the `Date` field I have seen this:

`$invJoinDate =  date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row["invJoinDate"]));`

Converting to a specific format using `date()` and `strtotime` which seems fine although a question arises of what to do with dates before 1970?

Anyway I attempted the same logic on the `DateTime` field and the value returned was `01/01/1970` which to me indicates a problem.

I then looked at PHP's `DateTime` class and tried this:

```
$invOnboardDate = new DateTime($row["invOnboardDate"]);
$invOnboardDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I ran this code and it returned an error.

**Recoverable fatal error:** Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Now, this is a fairly obvious error, but how can I display the textual value?

I am using the variables mentioned above in an array which I write to a CSV. It basically has this format:

```
$data = array(
    "key" => $var
);
```

In future should I just stick to a singular date manipulation class?

I realised I never actually mentioned the values:

One is: 2018-03-14 10:56:20
The other is: 2018-03-14

Comment: What is the value of `$row["invOnboardDate"]`?

Comment: 2018-03-14 10:56:20

Comment: The standard datetime format.

Comment: "the same logic on the DateTime field and the value returned was 01/01/1970".  Can you show your code that does that?  It should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `format` method of a DateTime *returns* a string - it does not change the object in any way. So your call to

```
$invOnboardDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

.. does nothing, except to return a formatted date that is not being used or assigned to anything.

When you're trying to write the value to a new CSV file, the variable is still pointing to the `DateTime` object, which is then attempted to be cast to a string - which fails with the exception you've given.

Assign the formatted version of the date:

```
$data = array(
    "key" => $invOnboardDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
);
```

.. so that's being used when outputting CSV instead.

Comment: See, I feel like this should have been obvious. I assumed the string would become the value of the variable.